# select with datalist (or alternative)

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-datalist

Because the following code doesn't work:

```html
<datalist id="somelist">
  <option>these</option>
  <option>options</option>
  <option>should</option>
  <option>appear</option>
  <option>in</option>
  <option>all</option>
  <option>selects</option>
</datalist>

<select list="somelist" name="first"></select>
<select list="somelist" name="another"></select>
<select list="somelist" name="last"></select>
```

Is there a good way to populate multiple selects with the same options? The problem with the following code is that it would have to use JavaScript to make sure they select something from the list (I'm looking for a more "elegant" solution):

```html
<datalist id="somelist">
  <option>these</option>
  <option>options</option>
  <option>should</option>
  <option>appear</option>
  <option>in</option>
  <option>all</option>
  <option>inputs</option>
</datalist>

<input list="somelist" name="first" />
<input list="somelist" name="another" />
<input list="somelist" name="last" />
```

Comment: There is no way to do this without javascript, sorry. You could either use JS to dynamically populate the selects based on a shared list, or to check if a value entered in one of the inputs is present in the datalist.